# Is it possible to query over DocumentReference[] array?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

`// Create a reference to the cities collection`

`var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");`

`// Create a query against the collection.`

`var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");`

From documentation it is possible to query collection. (CollectionReference type)

But I am having document that contains array of references, which has type DocumentReference[] and I am curious is it possible to achieve query over DocumentReference[]?
Something like:

`someCities : DocumentReference[];`

`someCities.where("street", "==", "School street")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query a DocumentReference array type field, you will have to use an [array-contains query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), and pass a DocumentReference type object to it.  It won't work with a string.

```
const ref = db.collection('coll').doc('doc');
db.collection('coll').where('refField', 'array-contains', ref);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, not actualy what I expected, but I solved a problem  with for loop through my array of reference with calling get() function to get data what reference are representing.